# angular2 config outDir

Tags: typescript, angular, lite-server

i create my first project and started on [angular 2 getstarted](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

I changed my config tsconfig.json with

```
{

"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "system",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "outDir": "dist"  <---- NEW 
 },
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules",
     "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

and I add on my package.json "lite": "lite-server  --baseDir ./dist"

Why the app don't start? Please Help me. Thank's Marco.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't pass `baseDir` argument to `lite-server`. Although, I don't see the cli arguments documented neither in [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) nor in [github](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server). You have to have a `bs-config.json` file.

```
{
   "server": { "baseDir": "./dist" }
}
```

Of course,that would require you to move `index.html` to inside `dist/`